# ignoring the '' quotes in the Like command

Tags: db2, command, sql-like

I have a  column having  values  of:
Status changed from 'Closed' to 'Transferred'
Status changed from 'Resolved' to 'Transferred'

I have to get these two column values using Like command.

But if I keep like command there is 'Closed'(Single quotes) are there. 
So that my query is not pulling the correct result .

can anyone please tell me how to ignore '' while using Like command?

Comment: Please show some sample data in a table.  Perhaps those single quotes are just an artifact.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Can you show an example of your sql command too?